# Taylor expanion of exponential matrix

Tags: matrices, taylor-expansion

I've been reading about Lie groups, and came across the following expansion that left me confused:

Let
$$
A = e^{i\lambda X_a} \text{  and  } B = e^{i\lambda X_b}
$$
for matrices $X_a$ and $X_b$, and let
$$
C = BAB^{-1}A^{-1} \approx I + \lambda^2[X_a,X_b]
$$
I tried writing out the terms explicitly, but I'm not getting a commutator. How does this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think taylor expansions:
$$ A = \exp (  i \lambda X_a) =1 + i \lambda X_a - \lambda^2  X_a^2 + O ( \lambda^3)$$
$$ B = \exp ( i \lambda X_b) = 1 + i \lambda X_b - \lambda^2 X_b^2  + O ( \lambda^3)$$
$$ A^{-1} = 1 - i \lambda X_a - \lambda^2 X_a^2 + O ( \lambda^3)$$
$$ B^{-1} = 1 - i \lambda X_b - \lambda^2 X_b^2 + O ( \lambda^3)$$
Write out the product up to second order to obtain
$$ BAB^{-1}A^{-1} = 1  + \lambda^2 [X_a,X_b] + O( \lambda^3)$$

Comment: I just figured it out a second ago!